# String slicing in python issue

Tags: python, string, binary, slice, decode

I'm writing a simple program to decode a binary string given by:

```
bin_str = "101100001101100001"
```

At the start, if the first character is represented by "1", then the next eight characters are decoded which would be "01100001" where i pass "01100001" into the function to obtain it's ascii representation.

```
def convert_ascii(binary):
    c = chr(int(binary, 2))
    return c
```

Passing in "01100001" into the above function would yield "a" which is the first character decoded. Moving on, the next character at index 9 is also represented by "1" hence the next eight characters will also be decoded which is "01100001". Passing in to the above would also yield "a".

```
lst = []
fixed_length = 8
i = 0
while i < len(bin_str):
    if binary[i] == "1":
        fl_bin = binary[i+1:fixed_length+1] #issue here
        ascii_rep = convert_ascii(fl_bin)
        lst.append(ascii_rep)
        i+=fixed_length+1
```

The problem I'm facing is slicing up the particular string of length 8 which is "01100001" from the original bin_str where i tried slicing by [i+1:fixed_length+1] but on the second phase, the fl_bin became "" instead of the next "01100001".

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: slicing is `from:to`, not `from:length`, so try `binary[i+1:i+1+fixed_length+1]` or `binary[i+1:i+fixed_length+2]`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do this is to create a regular expression that matches `1` followed by exactly eight `1` or `0` characters, and then use `re.findall()` to find all non-overlapping occurrences of this pattern in the string. By using a non-capturing group, you can even keep the initial `1` digit from being included in the results (although if you didn't do this, it's trivial to slice off that digit).

```
import re
reg_ex = "(?:1)([01]{8})"

bin_str = "101100001101100001"
ascii_rep = "".join(chr(int(byte, 2)) for byte in re.findall(reg_ex, bin_str))
```

As a bonus, this allows the groups in teh source string to be separated (by spaces, or words, or anything that's not a `1` followed by 8 `0`s or `1`s) for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

Using `iter` and `next` to cycle through if `next` produces a `1` then create a sublist of the next 8 items, append that to the main list and repeat until the generator is exhausted.

```
bin_str = "101100001101100001" 
a = iter(bin_str) 
lst = []

while True:
    try:
        b = next(a)
        z = []
        if b == '1':
            for i in range(8):
                z.append(next(a))
            lst.append(''.join(z))
    except StopIteration:
        break

print(lst)
# ['01100001', '01100001']
```